# Retrieve values from MYSQL db to show in radionbuttons

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a problem retrieving value from database that must show in radiobuttons. For example I have to select all "petType" and show in radiobuttons, but they must not repeat.
I have two values "cat" and "dog" but it only shows me radiobutton with "dog".
  Here's the code, it doesn't give my any errors.

```
/* Select all categories from PetType table */
$query = "SELECT * FROM PetType ORDER BY petType"; 
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
or die ("Couldn't execute query."); 

/* Display text before form */
echo "<div style='margin-left: .1in'>\n
<h1 style='text-align: center'>Pet Catalog</h1>\n
<h2 style='text-align: center'>The following animal friends are waiting for you.</h2>\n
<p style='text-align: center'>Find just what you want and hurry in to the store to pick      up your new friend.</p>
<h3>Which pet are you interested in?</h3>\n";

/* Create form containing selection list */
echo "<form action='ShowPets.php' method='POST'>\n";
echo "<table cellpadding='5' border='1'>";
$counter=1; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
extract($row);
//echo "<tr><td valign='top' width='20%' style='font-weight: bold; font-size:  1.2em'\n";
echo "<input type= \"radio\" name=\"interest\" value='$petType'";
if( $counter == 1 )
{
echo "checked='checked'";
}
echo ">$petType</td>"; 
//echo "<td>$typeDescription</td></tr>";
$counter++;
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<p><input type='submit' value='Select Pet Type'> </form></p>\n"; 
?>
```

Comment: is that two values are displaying ?

Comment: no just one value is displaying, but i need both to be displayed.

Comment: could you try the query on phpmyadmin to check whether it is  returning two values SELECT * FROM PetType ORDER BY petType

Comment: I checked and it returns only one value.

Comment: :) thats why it is displaying one radio button

Comment: how do i fix this problem? :)

Comment: add one more row in the db with new petType then run the same script . It should work and let me know if it worked for you

Comment: I added a few more row with different petType but it still return only one value

Answer (score 0):

Your html is not valid.

Put `<tr>` and `<td>` tags in to the table, and spaces where appropriate.

Eg

```
echo "<tr><td><input type= \"radio\" name=\"interest\" value='$petType' ";
if( $counter == 1 )
{
    echo "checked='checked'";
}
echo ">$petType</td></tr>";
```

Comment: I did what you said, still doesn't show other values

Comment: I said that before you told everyone that there was only one entry in the database. But just to be clear: how many rows are in the `PetType` table? And what does the html source for your page show inside the table?

Comment: i never said there was only one entry, there are 3 rows and petType is a field name not a table

Comment: Then your problem is this: `SELECT * FROM PetType ORDER BY petType`. You're selecting from the table called PetType, which doesn't exist - or, if it does, isn't the right table. Also, I assumed when you said "I checked and it returns only one value" that you were replying to the previous comment asking how many values in the table.

Comment: that's exactly where the problem was, i fixed it. I guess i wasn't very clear :)

Comment: Glad to hear you(!) fixed it. No, you weren't very clear at all.